# Definition of $\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R.$ Can someone give me the definition of$$\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\:\:\text{and}\;\;\limsup_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$$
and a reference in which I can find the properties of $\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ && $\limsup_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} \inf_{x \geq y} f(x),
\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} \sup_{x \geq y} f(x)
$$
See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior). References for $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ can be found on any introductory analysis book.

Comment: you mean $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{y\to\infty}\sup _{x\geq y}f(x)$$ ??

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. In layman terms, f(x) itself might  not converge, but we take all  it's convergent subsequences, and find the largest and smallest limits amongst them.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. It is fixed.